# sql performance problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, query-performance

I have a database with 24M records in SQL Server 2000.

When I run this query

```
select * from cdr
where starttime between '2011-05-15 00:00:00.000' and '2011-05-16 00:00:00.000'
```

and even this

```
declare @MinDate char(30) ,@MaxDate char(30)
set @MinDate=substring(convert(char,(getdate()-1), 120),1,10)+' 00:00:00.000'
set @MaxDate=substring(convert(char,(getdate()), 120),1,10)+' 00:00:00.000'
select * from cdr
where starttime between '2011-05-15 00:00:00.000' and @MaxDate
```

it runs very fast and return 3500 records in firs 10 seconds, note that `starttime` is `char(30)` in database

But when I run this query it just return 32 records in 10~60 seconds

```
declare @MinDate char(30), @MaxDate char(30)

set @MinDate = substring(convert(varchar, (getdate()-1), 120),1,10)+' 00:00:00.000'
set @MaxDate = substring(convert(varchar, (getdate()), 120),1,10)+' 00:00:00.000'

select * from cdr

where starttime between @MinDate and @MaxDate
```

:: @MinDate value is 2011-05-15 00:00:00.000

Note  that `starttime` is indexed in my database

I want to know what is my problem?

Comment: Well, one obvious problem is that you say your `StartTime` column is `VARCHAR(30)` - however, your criteria you use `@MinDate` and `@MaxDate` are defined as `CHAR(30)` which means they'll be padded to the defined length with spaces. This both wastes space, as well as requires conversion between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` - if your column's type is `VARCHAR(30)`, I would make the search criteria's datatype  `VARCHAR(30)` as well

Comment: Second obvious problem: do you **really** need all columns from your `cdr` table?? If not - **explicitly specify** the columns you need - and only those you really truly need. This cuts back query and data transfer time

Comment: Have you tried explicitly converting MinDate / MaxDate back to DateTime in your query?

Comment: to runonthespot: it is not possible to convert to date , some dates are not real dates.

Comment: Have you compared execution plans of both runs? Can you post them?

Comment: hard to post,with a select "top 10" both plans are same but with "top 100" are not same !

Answer (score 0):

Sql server probably has a query plan cached for the query with 2 parameters that is not optimal for your parameter values. In sqlserver 2008 you can use the Optimize for unknown hint. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/11/26/optimize-for-unknown-a-little-known-sql-server-2008-feature.aspx
In SQL server 2000 you can try one of the other options mentioned in the article.

Comment: same problem for select * from cdr where starttime between  @MinDate and '2011-05-16 00:00:00.000' exists !

Comment: Try using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before executing the query

Answer (score 0):

Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996713/sql-like-query-slow-if-using-declare-parameter-but-fast-if-not/5996778#5996778) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981894/why-doesnt-this-query-use-the-proper-index/5982614#5982614). Use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`